# Python List Slicing with Arbitrary Indices

Tags: python, list, slice

Is there a better way to extract arbitrary indices from a list in python?

The method I currently use is:

```
a = range(100)
s = [a[i] for i in [5,13,25]]
```

Where a is the array I want to slice, and [5,13,25] are the elements that I want to get.  It seems much more verbose than the Matlab equivalent:

```
a = 0:99;
s = a([6,14,26])
```

Comment: "It seems much more verbose than the Matlab". They're different languages.  What did you expect?  Python is **less** verbose than Java.

Comment: Python indices are 0-based. Your `5` means the sixth element. A 1-based language would have a `6` there. How come Matlab needs `4`? Does it start from -1?

Comment: This way is actually very readable, and I like it.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = range(100)
>>> itemgetter(5,13,25)(a)
(5, 13, 25)
```

Comment: Note this edge condition if using a list as the indexes:  indexes = [1,]; itemgetter(*indexes)(a) ----> returns an integer, not a tuple

Comment: Thank you! With this function, it must be the first time I encounter a real need for unpack * operator.

Comment: Nice, I wish this were default behavior - if it's going to go to the trouble and tell me it can't accept tuple indices it might as well try and use the tuple for something first.  I came here after getting used to the idea from addressing IPython cluster nodes in a similar fashion.

Comment: Note what @DarrenRinger means here is that if the indices you want are in a list you would write `itemgetter(*indices)(list)`

Answer (score 37):

If you are a Matlab user, but want to use Python, check out [numpy](https://numpy.org/):

```
In [37]: import numpy as np

In [38]: a = np.arange(100)

In [39]: s = a[[5,13,25]]

In [40]: s
Out[40]: array([ 5, 13, 25])
```

Here is a [comparison of NumPy and Matlab](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html), and here is a table of common [Matlab commands and their equivalents in NumPy](https://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html).

Answer (score 14):

There is no "ready made" way  - the way you do it is quite ingenious, and you could use it.
If you have a lot of that trough your code, you might want to use a subclass of list that would use a syntax just like matlabs - it can be done in a few lines code, the major burden is that you'd have to work always use this new class instead of the built-in lists.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if not isinstance(index, tuple):
            return list.__getitem__(self, index)
        return [self[i] for i in index]
```

And on the console:

```
>>> m = MyList(i * 3 for i in range(100))
>>> m[20, 25,60]
[60, 75, 180]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more robust version of the excellent accepted @John La Rooy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108109/304209). It passes the provided doctests. It always returns a list.

```
def slice_by_index(lst, indexes):
    """Slice list by positional indexes.

    Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108109/304209.

    Args:
        lst: list to slice.
        indexes: iterable of 0-based indexes of the list positions to return.

    Returns:
        a new list containing elements of lst on positions specified by indexes.

    >>> slice_by_index([], [])
    []
    >>> slice_by_index([], [0, 1])
    []
    >>> slice_by_index(['a', 'b', 'c'], [])
    []
    >>> slice_by_index(['a', 'b', 'c'], [0, 2])
    ['a', 'c']
    >>> slice_by_index(['a', 'b', 'c'], [0, 1])
    ['a', 'b']
    >>> slice_by_index(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1])
    ['b']
    """
    if not lst or not indexes:
        return []
    slice_ = itemgetter(*indexes)(lst)
    if len(indexes) == 1:
        return [slice_]
    return list(slice_)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you would do:

```
    a = list(range(99)) 
    s = [a[5], a[13], a[25]]
```

this seems to be almost identical to the matlab version.

Comment: If I had to guess, it might be because this answer does not work in Python 3 (a is not indexable).