# Python: an efficient way to slice a list with a index list

Tags: python, performance, list, indexing, slice

I wish to know an efficient way and code saving to slice a list of thousand of elements

example:

```
b = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"] 
index = [1,3,6,7]
```

I wish a result like as:

```
c = ["b","d","g","h"]
```

Comment: Almost the same question with more solutions: [Python List Slicing with Arbitrary Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9106065/320437)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The most direct way to do this with lists is to use a list comprehension:

```
c = [b[i] for i in index]
```

But, depending on exactly what your data looks like and what else you need to do with it, you could use numpy arrays - in which case:

```
c = b[index]
```

would do what you want, and would avoid the potential memory overhead for large slices - numpy arrays are stored more efficiently than lists, and slicing takes a view into the array rather than making a partial copy.

Comment: thanks lvc
I have this error message

c = b[index]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: @Gianni as I said in my answer, that will work if you use numpy arrays instead of lists. They can take all kinds of interesting things as indexes; lists can only take integers (and slices with integer arguments).

Comment: +1 for using a list comprehension. It's a good thing to teach newbies.